# Python pandas find starting/ending row and rounding numbers

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import urllib

url = 'http://cawcr.gov.au/staff/mwheeler/maproom/RMM/RMM1RMM2.74toRealtime.txt'
urllib.urlretrieve(url,'datafile.txt')

df = pd.read_table('datafile.txt', sep='\s+', header=None)
df.columns = ['year', 'month', 'day', 'n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4', 'type']
df = df[df.year > 1978] #new starting row is created, how do I find what the new starting row is
df = df[df.type < 'Prelim_value'] #new ending row is created, how do I find what the new ending row is

tda1 = []
for a in range(starting_row, ending_row):
    if a < starting_row+19:
        tda1.append(0.0)
    else:
        ch = df.ix[a:a+20, ['n1']]
        dc = np.round(ec,0)
        tda1.append(ec)
```

How do I find the starting row after chopping off the beginning of the file, ditto on finding the ending row?

Would I need to create a whole new dataframe if I wanted to keep everything together...aka, I want to have tda1 being right in line with n1.  If I access `tda1[1700]` and `n1[1700]` I want them to both be pointing to the same date.

As of yet I still can't get `df.iloc(0)['n1']` or any other combo of  to give me anything other than an error suggesting that DataFrame object is not an attribute of iloc.

Comment: you might want to try `df.iloc[0]` rather than `df.iloc(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

To quickly answer your last question, use:

```
import numpy as np
np.round(ec, 0)
```

For your first (series of) question(s), you don't give us any data to play with and your questions isn't very clear. Either way, you can always get the the first and last rows of *any* dataframe with `df.iloc[0]` and `df.iloc[-1]`, respectively.

#### Edits:

If you simply need to know how many rows you have, use `df.shape`. Here's a toy example:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame([
    (1977, 1, 1),
    (1978, 1, 2),
    (1979, 1, 3),
    (1980, 1, 4),
    (1977, 2, 1),
    (1978, 2, 2),
    (1979, 2, 3),
    (1980, 2, 4),
    (1977, 3, 1),
    (1978, 3, 2),
    (1979, 3, 3),
    (1980, 3, 4),
], columns=['year', 'a', 'b'])
print(df.to_string())
```

Which prints:

```
    year  a  b
0   1977  1  1
1   1978  1  2
2   1979  1  3
3   1980  1  4
4   1977  2  1
5   1978  2  2
6   1979  2  3
7   1980  2  4
8   1977  3  1
9   1978  3  2
10  1979  3  3
11  1980  3  4
```

And then:

```
df = df[df.year > 1978]
df = df[df.a < 3]
print(df.to_string())
```

which gives:

```
   year  a  b
2  1979  1  3
3  1980  1  4
6  1979  2  3
7  1980  2  4
```

Try this our yourself after executing everything above:

```
print(df.shape)

for row in range(df.shape[0]-1):
    print(df.iloc[row])
```

#### For rounding:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(4,4)))
rounded = np.round(df,1)
print(rounded.to_string())
     0    1    2    3
0 -1.2  1.9  0.7 -0.8
1 -0.5  0.9  1.6 -0.3
2  0.4 -0.2 -1.6 -0.2
3 -1.7  1.1  0.1 -0.6
```

Comment: Or use `head` and `tail`, but `iloc` is more powerful.

Comment: +1 @DSM: huh -- it never even occurred to me to you `tail` and `head` to access data. in my mind they've always simply been ways to preview something in an ipython notebook. perspective = changed

Comment: But within the confines of the program how do I reference the first and last rows.  'code'for a in range(first,last):  ????????  I have to be able to find the first/last row once I have trimmed the data down to what I want to use.  I can't loop through the data until I have found the first/last rows.  The last row changes daily so it isn't fixed.  In other programs I know I will be dealing with the same thing but with different data so the first/last rows won't be fixed values.  I will have to be able to find where the pointer gets moved to once I 'code'df = df[df.year > 1978]

Comment: @confused first/last rows are always at 0 and -1. However, it sounds like you actually need the shape of your filtered dataframe. see my edited repsonse

Comment: I just tried adding the line np.round(ec,0) into the program and it didn't round the number.  With or without the line I got the same result when I went to view it.

Comment: @confused you need to assign the output of `np.round` to a new variable. again, see my edited response.

Comment: After I trim the data and I go df.head(1), it takes me to the first date.  Good.  If I try to go and find the underlying data...aka, df.n1[1] it comes up and says KeyError: 1.  If instead I go and try df.n1[1675] it comes up with the first value.  When I df.head(1) the first thing that shows is 1675.  How do I read the 1675 from within the program.

Comment: I should have known better on the rounding issue.  My stupid fault.  Thanks.  Sometimes we all need to be hit over the head.

Comment: @confused you **really** need to use `iloc` -- as in `df.n1.iloc[0]`

Comment: When I use .iloc I keep getting the error 'Series' has no attribute iloc

Comment: @confused i had that backwards: `df.iloc[0]['n1']`. I just want to point out that a lot of discussion could be avoided if you had posted a copy/paste-able example script: http://sscce.org/

Comment: I've updated the code to include the download link of the data.  I think the download should work correctly as written.  For some my darn computer is trying to tell me urllib doesn't have the attribute urlretrieve.  What else is new?  I chop off the first 1675 and the last, roughly, 3-10 rows of data.  How do I find the new first row so I can take X day average of the data all the way through the remaining rows.  How do I go about creating a new column where that data gets stored that is in direct reference to the original data, another tda1[2000] and n1[2000] both point to the same day.