# Python where's the data

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to find the data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import urllib

url = 'http://cawcr.gov.au/staff/mwheeler/maproom/RMM/RMM1RMM2.74toRealtime.txt'
urllib.urlretrieve(url,'datafile.txt')

df = pd.read_table('datafile.txt', sep='\s+', header=None)
df.columns = ['year', 'month', 'day', 'n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4', 'type']
df = df[df.year > 1978]
df = df[df.type < 'Prelim_value:_OLR_&_NCEPop_wind']

tda1[]
for a in range(df.shape[0],-1):
#for a in range(firstrowofdata,lastrowofdata):
#where is the first row, where is the last row, how do I find out through the
#computer program.  I want to do this with several different data sources.
    print(df.iloc[a])
        if a < df.shape[0]+19:
                tda1.append(0.0)
```

First question is how do I strip off the header with Python 2.7.  With 3.3 the above code works fine but it doesn't strip off the header in 2.7.  Have had numerous problems going between the two versions of Python...it's maddening.  I have 2.7 terminal installed and finally went out last night and changed over 2.7 shell as well.  Had been using/getting fed up with the discrepancies between 2.7 terminal and 3.3 shell I have been working with.

Once I download the data from the data source, one of many different sources I plan to use throughout the course of the program I'm starting to work on, I want to be able to strip off the unnecessary data and then do mathematical work with the remaining data and put the results into new columns right alongside the original data.  Aka, July 15, 2001 math calculations will be right beside the original data for July 15, 2001.  To accomplish this I need to find out where the first row of stripped data is located so I can set up the for-loop(firstrow,lastrow).  Until I can find out where both beginning of the stripped data is located and where the end of the stripped data is located I can't do anything else.  How do I retrieve the number that tells me where the first/last row is stored at?  I've been told previous to use head/tail or iloc.  When I try using df.iloc all I get is the error DataFrame has no attribute 'iloc'.  When I try to use df.head(0) or df.tail(-1) I get the first/last row showing up as the first number of the head or tail line.  How do I get that number though so I can actually use the number to set the first/last row of data from the computer program.  If I try:

```
n = df.head(0)
print (n)
```

It still gives me the same thing.  How do I strip off the row number from the entire head/tail line.

Secondly, I want to be able to perform the math calculations and then go back and add in columns to the dataframe.  Is this possible...how?  Can I put the math calc data right in place with where I have the original data stored, aka

```
df.columns = ['year', 'month', 'day', 'n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4', 'type', 'calc1', 'calc2', 'etc']
```

I want the data to all be in the same dataframe with the dates matching up.  If I take a 5 day moving average, for example, for the date ending July 1, 2001 I want the 5 day average put with the July 1, 2001 original data.  It just makes for much easier accessing of data.

So far I'm stumped on getting the first/last row to be able to progress any further with this project.  This is all I have right now.  I keep trying to make headway with zero luck.

Comment: I don't know much about Pandas, but your first loop is probably not going to work right. `range(df.shape[0],-1)` will be an empty sequence (unless `df.shape[0]` is negative, and I have no idea what that would mean). If you want to be iterating from `df.shape[0]` down to zero, you need to give a negative step to `range`.

Comment: not sure how this question is different than the one you already asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692140/python-pandas-find-starting-ending-row-and-rounding-numbers?rq=1

Comment: This is several questions. It's best to keep is SO thread to a single issue/question. Secondly, your code doesn't run. See http://sscce.org/ for info on why it should. Lastly, please show example output of what you are trying to achieve, even if it relies on fake/synthetic/toy data.

Comment: Don't have internet access at home.  If the code worked I wouldn't have the ask any questions would I. What I'm hoping to achieve is knowing where the first/last row of trimmed data is located so I can set up a for-loop to go through the data and perform mathematical calculations with the values and then send those results back into new columns attached directly to the same date as the date in question.  Later on once all this is finished I will graph the data.  What's so hard about understanding that?  The code works fine down to the for-loop.  Can't get that to work, hence the questions.

Answer (score 0):

You should skip the first two rows explicitly (it's confusing this isn't required on python 3):

```
df = pd.read_csv('datafile.txt', sep='\s+', header=None, skiprows=2)
```